# Add onClick event to a group element (svg) with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, dom-events

I'm trying to add an onClick event to an existing svg. Right now I have this :

```
<g id="Group" onClick={this.clickGroup.bind(this, 1)}>
```

Which *somewhat* works but not entirely... The event fires when I click the group but the "zone" that is clickable isn't the same as the group I want to be clickable (it seems completely random to me).

Is there any better way to add events to a `<g>`element (with React ?) ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A `g` element is just an empty container; it can not fire events by itself.

If you run [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/y3pLss08/), you'll see that you can trigger the `click` event by clicking on the children of the `g` element, but you can't if you click in the empty space between them.

You have to use actual shapes to fire events in SVG.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does that mean that the best solution would be to wrap all the paths that form a shape inside something like a rectangle ?

Comment: You can add a transparent rectangle on top of your shapes and attach an event on it. If someone has a more elegant solution, would be glad to see it.

Comment: I was just going through the svg docs. It seems that events can be added to <g> elements. Please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/Events#Global_Event_Attributes)

Comment: @Shubham Indeed you can. But as @anthony-dugois said, `<g>` is an empty container, so if you do not populate that container with other elements, you won't be able to fire events from it.

Answer (score 38):

Use style pointer-events as bounding-box to make the group clickable any where on the group.Even at the empty places

```
<g id="Group" onClick={this.clickGroup.bind(this, 1)} style="pointer-events: bounding-box;">
```

Comment: The answer box is only for complete answers to the question. This feels like it would be better suited as a comment. Changing the text so that it directly addresses the question that was asked improves the long-term value of the answer and helps to prevent it from being deleted during review.

Comment: I dread this answer being a comment. I have just spent two hours trying to figure out how have a `g` element the actual target when the `onClick` handler is on one of its ancestors. This answer was the breakthrough.

Comment: `pointer-events: bounding-box` is not documented though
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Not supported in safari