# Handle on click to SVG element from string React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have SVG loaded by Ajax from server, and I'm using it in container as `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as follows. `base64` variable contains encoded string of SVG element.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: atob(base64)}}/>
```

It works correctly. But I want to handle on click to svg parts and fire events from them. Is that possible under React?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add onClick event to a group element (svg) with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706869/add-onclick-event-to-a-group-element-svg-with-react)

Comment: it shouldnt, on that question they are speaking about direct component SVG, not generated from string :)

Comment: why not use onClick in that div? 
`<div onClick={this.myfunction} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: atob(base64)}}/>` I have never used `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it should work

Comment: because it is firing just onclick event directly to svg, not components of that svg

Comment: AFAIK `dSIH` doesn't process incoming HTML as JSX--it just inserts it directly into the DOM, meaning React doesn't know about events from within that DOM. You might be able to do something horrible to attach event handlers after its been rendered. You might be able to use something like https://github.com/aknuds1/html-to-react etc.

Comment: i have same usecase, please update thread with Solution you implemented ?