# Making an SVG Element clickable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, onclick

I am trying to get an onClick event working in React.

The SVG contains multiple objects (primarly circle).

Using "onClick" results in a very weird behavoiur: For every created circle the onClick element gets triggered one time right after loading the data (Print out: 6 times "TEST"). But i can't click the circles manually.

The implementaion of the "Container":

```
<svg viewBox={viewboxLocation.x + " " + viewboxLocation.y + " " + viewboxSize.x * viewboxScale+ " " + viewboxSize.y *  viewboxScale} >
            <g stroke="black" fill="white" strokeWidth="2">
                {coordinates.results.map((milestone => 
                {
                    return <MilestoneSVG key={"Milestone" + milestone.milestoneName} posX={milestone.x} posY={milestone.y} milestoneName={milestone.milestoneName} onClick={console.warn("TEST")}/>
                }
                ))};
                [...]

            </g>

 </svg>
```

The implementaion of the Circle:

```
function Circle(props) {
const displayText = props.displayText;

let size = props.size ;
let posX = props.posX;
let posY = props.posY;
if(!size){
size = 20;
}
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <circle cx={posX} cy={posY} r={size} fill="white"/>
        <text x={posX} y={posY} textAnchor="middle"dy=".3em">{displayText} </text>
    </React.Fragment>
);

}

 export default Circle;
```

I also tried to add "onClick={props.onClick}" to the . but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: For a better reference you can read this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706869/add-onclick-event-to-a-group-element-svg-with-react

Comment: Thank you! If someone else finds this issue in the future: Adding "onClick={() => console.warn("TEST")} style="pointer-events: bounding-box;" to the <MilestoneSVG> AND adding onClick={props.onClick} to the <circle> fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

The main issue because you don't put the code in a function body, `onClick={() => console.warn("TEST")}`